# click event in js datatables (broken with paging)

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, paging

I want to have a button with js click in each `datatable row`, but my code is broken by `datatables paging` system - default datatable option. Click works only on first datatable page. My only idea is to disable paging and create scrolable datatable, but I would prefer to keep paging for better UX.

Example datatable:

```
<table id="data_tables">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Action</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
    <tr>      
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- Datarow 1 -->
    <tr>
        <td><input type='button' class='my_button' data-id='1' value='click' /></td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Wayne</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Datarow 2 -->      
    <tr>
        <td><input type='button' class='my_button' data-id='2' value='click' /></td>
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>Kent</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Click event handler

```
//simple on() in jquery would do the trick in normal <table>
$( ".my_button" ).on( "click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    alert(id); 
});
```

Is there a way to workaround this problem? Or maybe datatable api solution?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/vy0fjpbg/ I hope its fine, becouse I use jsfiddle rarelly.

Comment: Ask yourself this question "Does this fiddle reproduce my problem?", if that answer is yes then it's fine, if the answer is no then you need to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It does. However Arthur Shveidas solution works fine. Thanx anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#data_tables").on("click", ".my_button", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
});
```